# Regardin Flex mobile alert

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I am creating an application using flex mobile but could not find how to show alerts using flex.
So can anyone please tell how to show the alert in flex mobile , mx alert don't  work in this and i could not find an alternative in spark.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use the native alert popup (a title & message with 1-2 buttons like Ok|Cancel) I suggest using [ANE Native Alert](http://extensionsforair.com/extensions/nativealert/)

Answer (score 0):

You can either make your own pop ups, or if you don't want the hassle.

There is a Native Extension called AirAlert that will display the native pop ups. You can find it here:

[Air Alert Git Hub Page](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Alert)

It works well on both platforms.